# Progress dialog issue in Android app

Tags: java, android

I'm having trouble with the way I am trying to get the progress dialogue to work.

First I initialise the progress dialogue in my searchable activity class as so:

```
ProgressDialog pd;
```

Then I show the progress dialogue when a search is executed in my dosearch method:

```
public void doSearch(String query) {

    pd = ProgressDialog.show(SearchableActivity.this, "Last Fm", "Searching Tracks...");


    String[] result = new String[] {"searching..."};

    AlbumSearchService service = new AlbumSearchService(query);
    service.addListener(this);
    thread = new Thread(service);
    thread.start();

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> (this ,
                     R.layout.album_list_cell,
                     R.id.text,
                     result));
    Log.v("blah", "doSearch was called");

    service.run();
}
```

And finally, once the search is complete, I dismiss the progress indicator in my service complete method.

```
 pd.dismiss();
```

I fail to see what I'm doing wrong, whenever I commence a search, the progress dialogue feature does not appear please help :(

Thank you!

Edit:

Here's my full code for those with a sharp eye. I think it may be a thread issue but i have no clue.

public class SearchableActivity extends ListActivity implements ServiceListener {
    private Thread thread;
    private ArrayList searchResults;
    ProgressDialog pd;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search);
    searchResults = new ArrayList<JSONObject>(); // initialise array list to
                                                    // hold the results so
                                                    // we can do something
                                                    // with them

    // this gets the intent being sent over
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);

        doSearch(query);

    }

}

@Override
// this method handles what happens when a user clicks a result.
// the search item is broadcasted for other people to use.
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    if (position < searchResults.size()) { // if the position is less than
                                            // the size of the results array
                                            // then...
        Intent result = new Intent(); // create a new intent called result.
        result.setAction(SEARCH_BROADCAST); // place the broadcast message
                                            // on the intent.
        result.putExtra("result", searchResults.get(position).toString()); // add
                                                                            // extended
                                                                            // data
                                                                            // to
                                                                            // the
                                                                            // intent
        this.sendBroadcast(result);

        this.finish();

    }
}

public void doSearch(String query) {

    pd = ProgressDialog.show(SearchableActivity.this, "Last Fm",
            "Searching Tracks...");

    String[] result = new String[] { "searching..." };

    AlbumSearchService service = new AlbumSearchService(query);
    service.addListener(this);
    thread = new Thread(service);
    thread.start();

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.album_list_cell,
            R.id.text, result));
    Log.v("blah", "doSearch was called");

    service.run();

}

public void ServiceComplete(AbstractService service) {

    if (pd.isShowing()) {
        pd.dismiss();
    }

    if (!service.hasError()) {
        AlbumSearchService albumService = (AlbumSearchService) service;
        String[] result = new String[albumService.getResults().length()];
        searchResults.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < albumService.getResults().length(); i++) {
            try {
                searchResults.add(albumService.getResults()
                        .getJSONObject(i)); // gets the json object for each
                                            // result and adds to array
                result[i] = albumService.getResults().getJSONObject(i)
                        .getString("name");
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                result[i] = "Error";
            }
        }

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.album_list_cell, R.id.text, result));
    } else {
        String[] result = new String[] { "No Results" };

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.album_list_cell, R.id.text, result));
    }
}

public static final String SEARCH_BROADCAST = "search_result_selected";
```

}

Comment: Is the search working aside from the dialog?  Any problems showing up in Logcat?

Comment: No issues, and the search works just fine

Comment: What is the problem? What happens? ProgressBar doesn't dismiss? I think it's because you update UI from the new thread.

Comment: Marco, I said it doesn't appear. Please read before making a response. Thank you.

Comment: Calling service.run() after service.start() is a mistake. Calling service.run() is probably not what you want.

Comment: If you are not explicitly setting the progress anywhere, you'd probably better make the progress bar *indeterminate* (extra parameter in Show)

Comment: Thanks doctoror. fixed my issue by removing that line :D